# HD read error while booting Linux

Tags: linux, hardware-failure

I have been dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my laptop since the past 3 years and all was working fine until I started getting logs like

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE

sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense key: Medium Error [Current][discreptor]
```

I figured it was a hardware problem and ignored it as long as I could until the HD crashed on me. Then I got a brand new HD and put on Windows and Ubuntu afresh on it but the problem still persists.

Any help?